# How do I change from the clock mode in tmux

Tags: tmux

So I am in a `tmux` session and I accidentally pressed `C-b t`. Now that happens to be a "big clock" mode. I can't get back out of this mode. :((. Help.. The session has a long-standing process running in the background.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to either press q or Esc

Comment: In the current version, you can press any key to quit the clock mode.